# Association between a continuous and dichotomous variable in SAS

Tags: sas, associations, correlation

My dataset contains two variables: Gender(M/F) and Total Score. Total score is a continuous variable and has values like 23.4, 25.4 etc. In total I have 150 records.

I wish to see whether there is any association between Gender and the Total score. I can use a Point Biserial correlation which measure the association between a dichotomous and continuous variable. Can you please help in solving this in SAS. I do not want a correlation coefficient's value for every score, I want a p value to determine the association overall. Thank you!

Comment: PROC TTEST or ANOVA

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I can do a t test to check the difference between the two means based on gender. However, I have similar dataset which talks about time since last event and the success of the event, again a continuous and a dichotomous variable. The intent is to see whether time since last event has any association with the success of the current event? Do you think t test would again be the correct method here?

Comment: That sounds like a new and different question. Is this question resolved? Typically this question would get closed, please review the guidelines here [ask]

Comment: For time analysis, it depends on if you need to account for censoring or not. It also depends on your exact context. You can take a look at survival analysis, proc lifetest and phreg are the SAS procs that are relevant.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you can test for the difference in the means of `total_score`  between males and females with a t-test. In SAS, you may run:

```
proc ttest data = your_dataset_name;
class gender;
var total_score;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I can do a t test to check the difference between the two means based on gender. However, I have similar dataset which talks about time since last event and the success of the event, again a continuous and a dichotomous variable. The intent is to see whether time since last event has any association with the success of the current event? Do you think t test would again be the correct method here?

Comment: A t-test is one statistical tool to test if two groups are different regarding the average of a continuous variable. It can be applied to any dataset if this is what you want to test. It has some assumptions, regarding random sample. However, after your new description of the problem, I suspect that you are looking for a survival analysis. But I am no statistician. I think the right way to proceed is to check what is done in the literature of your field of work/study.